# Why the old second text line didn't replace with new text during for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

While the video is playing, I have 2 lines of text which the first line is new text and the second line is old text that been move up from first line. However, during for loop, the second line doesn't even replace at all because both line display the same text. Anyone can tell me what wrong with it? "text" is first line and "second" is second line. Please help. Here my javascript code and website is [a link]http://www.cs.rit.edu/~rskics/study/caption2/test.html (work on firefox),

```
var subtitleArray = new Array(); //stored all values from XML caption file

var tempText = "";  

    $(document).ready(function(){
                            //alert("get caption 1");
                            getCaption();

                            var subtitle2 = document.getElementById('subtitle2');

                            var video = document.getElementById('video');



                            $("#video").bind('timeupdate',function(){


                                var text = "", cap = "";

                                    for( var i = 0; i < subtitleArray.length;i++)
                                    {

                                        var cueStart = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][0]);
                                        var cueEnd = cueStart + parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][1]);

                                        cap = subtitleArray[i][2];

                                        if (video.currentTime >= cueStart && video.currentTime <= cueEnd) {
                                           text = cap;   
                                        }


                                        if ( text != tempText && text != "" ) {
                                        console.log( text );
                                        console.log(tempText);
                                            $("#second").html(text);
                                        }

                                        subtitle2.innerHTML = text;
                                        tempText = text;
                                        console.log( tempText );

                                    }
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: just a note, since you are already using jquery you can replace `getElementById('subtitle2')` with `$('#subtitle2')`. And you can also replace `innerHTML` with `html()` or `text()`.

Comment: what is `subtitleArray`?  That determines how often the loop will run.  Also note that `tempText` is a global variable, which may not be what you want.

Comment: subtitleArray have time start, duration, and text in each index. Yes, tempText declare in global variable as empty string to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, here a code

```
var tempText = "", prevText="";

$("#video").bind('timeupdate',function(){


                        var text = "", cap = "";

                            for( var i = 0; i < subtitleArray.length;i++)
                            {

                                var cueStart = parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][0]);
                                var cueEnd = cueStart + parseFloat(subtitleArray[i][1]);

                                cap = subtitleArray[i][2];

                                if (video.currentTime >= cueStart && video.currentTime <= cueEnd) {
                                   text = cap;   
                                }

                                if (tempText != text && text != "") {

                                    prevText = tempText;
                                    $("#second").html(prevText);
                                }

                                subtitle.innerHTML = text;

                                if ( text != "" ) {
                                    tempText = text;
                                }


                            }
                    });
```